# Apache POI encrypted .doc file cannot be opened in Word

Tags: encryption, apache-poi, doc

When I encrypted a simple doc file. like this [image]

it can be opened in Microsoft Word. When I change another complicated doc file like this
[image]

it cannot be opened in Microsoft Word. I do not know why.

```
public static boolean encrypDOC(String sourceFilePath, OutputStream out, String password) throws IOException {
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        HWPFDocument doc = null;
        try {
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(sourceFilePath));
            doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
            Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(password);
            doc.write(out);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            doc.close();
            fs.close();
            out.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRU6Y.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.